# WebService Task in Camunda

Tags: camunda

In Camunda BPM designer, I couldn't find activity and for invoking a REST or SOAP based webservices. Is it only possible to invoke through wiring code? How do I pass payload to the code if it needs to be written using java code.

Regards,

Phani

Answer (score 12):

You can invoke a Webservice inside a bpmn.

You can create a Task of type Service, and choose in Properties/Details/Implementation: Connector.

Next you configure Connector properties, setting:

Connector Id: **http-connector** (for rest json webservices) and
Input Parameters:

- **url** (e.g. http://localhost:8080/client?id=12
- **method** GET/POST
- **headers** type MAP: Accept application/json...

You receive the webservice response as Process Variables, configuring the Output parameters as follows :

- **response, type text, value ${response}**
- **returnCode, type text, value ${statusCode}**

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 4):

For start: please note that camundas claim is "developer friendly". It's never been the goal of camunda components to just "click together" a working process. If you are looking for such a solution, you should a) have a look at the [zero coding myth](https://network.camunda.org/whitepaper/1) and b) maybe choose another tool.

That being said, check out the [camunda-connect](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-connectors) framework, introduced with 7.2, it should do what you need (though it involves xml coding).

Answer (score 1):

For all but the most simple SOAP / REST calls, you'll need to go through java code. This takes a little getting used to when moving from other BPM platforms with extensive built-in webservice support. But trust me, java code is the way to go - import of transform / WSDL in the process definiton becomes such a holy mess.

I've written two CXF-based examples: [soap-cxf-service](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/servicetask/soap-cxf-service) and [soap-cxf-server-start](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/startevent/soap-cxf-server-start) which will get you started.

I recommend creating a maven artifact per webservice and just adding the required services as standard maven dependencies for your process project.

Comment: No, you can also call a rest api using service task.

Comment: @MuhmmadAbubakarIkram I'm not claiming otherwise?